# Using GitBash as my default terminal in VSCode, I'm unable to execute any of my C/C++ programs

Tags: c++, c, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

> GitBash not working. Haven't been able to identify the error as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character represents the start of an escape sequence. You must escape it using another backslash character, or the character after it will be interpreted literally.

```sh
cd "f:\VSC\C\reverse_sentence\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "f:\VSC\C\reverse_sentence\"main
```

When you are closing the first string, there is a backslash before the double quotes, meaning that they were interpreted literally. Then, the start of the second string is interpreted as the end of the string. You can see that from the syntax highlighting.

This script should work:

```sh
cd "f:\\VSC\\C\\reverse_sentence\\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "f:\\VSC\\C\\reverse_sentence\\main"
```

Comment: sorry but im not unable to get what you're saying. You've provide a script but what should i do with it?

Comment: You can use that script instead of what you used before